# How do I serve an app engine version via subdomain when my app runs through Google Apps?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps

I'm trying to use a subdomain to serve a matching version id with Google App Engine and Google Apps.  I've gone through the documentation but it's still unclear to me.

1. On this page regarding custom domains, it says I'm in a special case for using Google Apps.  test.example.com -> to load "test" version of the application.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/domain -

> Note that the instructions on this page are for App Engine apps that use an ordinary HTTP connection and are not served through Google Apps. Here are some related procedures that require different instructions:

This leads me to here https://support.google.com/a/answer/91080

It looks like the only way to add this subdomain in Google Apps is the *Sites URL* field.

Will the Sites URL correspond to the App Engine version ID?[image]

Comment: this looks like it means something but you are conflating so many terms it is impossible to know what you are actually asking. *App Engine apps that use an ordinary HTTP connection and are not served through Google Apps.* this makes no sense what so ever!

Comment: I'm probably confusing myself as well; that line was cut from the documentation.  It seems there are two types of subdomain to run on app engine: those running on Google Apps (google.com/a) and those that aren't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to use Google Apps to map an appengine app to a domain if you need https. Right now, Google Apps is the only way you can upload an SSL cert - hence this restriction.

If you do map your appengine app to a domain through google apps, you can do what you want by using wildcard subdomain mapping. [Read more here.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/domain#more_about_wildcard_subdomain_mapping).

The whole process is tedious, slow, and painful, and thats only when its not confusing, so put aside a good few hours to make all the changes and wait for DNS to propagate.

Comment: Thanks - I was under the impression that the wildcard subdomain mapping wouldn't work for a Google Apps domain but I'll reread and give it a try.  I ran through this once before and it did work, it didn't point to the correct version I was expecting, in their example the beta.example would point to the version 'beta'.

Comment: Any subdomain that doesn't match a module or version is sent to the default version/module. Supposedly.

Comment: Yeah that's the weird thing it's still serving the default version even though I have it 1:1 match with the subdomain currently.  I'll keep digging.

Comment: I got it to work by using the wildcard mapping.  It must be a wildcard, you can't map the subdomain by the name itself.   *.example.com NOT beta.example.com.  The asterisk will map the string beta to version beta.